# LDAP 389: Auto user creation at the client machines

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, 389-ds

I have setup an 389 directory server on Centos 6. User authentication works fine, however, I have to create individual users on each client machine after creating the user at the directory server.

The  the pam_mkhomedir.so module seems to create home directories in case the user is already present in the local system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the answer and solution. It is pretty simple. Similar discussion has already been done long back.

[How can I require a certain group of users to login via LDAP while letting others use either LDAP or local login?](https://serverfault.com/questions/196255/how-to-allow-a-certain-group-of-useres-to-only-login-via-ldap-while-others-can-u)

So here is snippet of my system-auth file for anyone looking for same.

```
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so
account     sufficient    pam_sss.so

session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=022
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your /etc/pam.d/system-auth & /etc/pam.d/password-auth like below.

```
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

For a home directory to be created automatically when a user logs in, You can use either the pam_oddjob_mkhomedir module or the pam_mkhomedir module. Because oddjob requires fewer permissions and works well with SELinux, you should always use pam_oddjob_mkhomedir module. If that module is not installed, then it falls back to the pam_mkhomedir module.

If you are trying to login using ssh, you have to do below as well.

Modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config to contain

> "UsePam yes"

```
# service sshd restart
# service oddjobd restart
```